# How to get the non null value of an item during group by in SQL

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a dataset where for a single employee the terminated date can be null or non-null as below:

```
Employee Terminated_Dt
1        NULL
1        2018-04-01
```

How to capture only the non-null value during group by on Employee to get the correct date?
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you try? Aggregation usually skips null values anyway. Provide your code and expected results and real (incorrect) results - otherwise we can't help :(

Comment: `max`? Its not clear from your questions.

Comment: hi, please provide some information, structure, query try, and excepted result.

Comment: Hi @DaleK... I have tried using max but it doesn't work for all cases.. For some Employees it does work but not for all having both null and a value.

Comment: How about a filter to your query that says Is not null ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but I think I can respond:

In this case the where clause remove the null entry from Terminated_Dt column. 
But if you wanna to get all employee (id) it's not respond because the employee with only null Terminated_Dt was not showing .. so you have to add some information and excepted output to have answer.

```
SELECT Employee, MAX(Terminated_Dt) AS 'Max_Terminated_Dt'
FROM #TEMP_EMPLOYEE
WHERE Terminated_Dt IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY Employee
```

Comment: Please explain how you are solving the problem, in addition to providing a query.

Comment: Yes but i didn't respond because the query wasn't clear :(, i'm sharing just a query it's can be not respond due to the poor explain.

Comment: You can explain how your query attempts to solve the problem you think it is. Otherwise you shouldn't answer.